# Intel wireless 7260 problems in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, intel

my internet connection is really slow and unstable sometimes and only on my Ubuntu machine =( can somebody help me

Comment: Same issue as this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/456603/intel-7260ac-not-working-with-ubuntu-14-04 (which includes myself. Se my bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1305305